# ngOnChanges not detecting changes unless polled

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a couple of components which pass data via events to each other. So I'm trying to utilize the OnEvents interface to do some action after something changes. So what I'm trying to do is simple: My map component receives an event from its child component using the `@Output` functionality. This then calls the `focusChart()` method. Up until this point everything is fine. The event arrives in the map component without issue. Then I attempt to set a variable on the map component which needs to then be passed to my chart component. This is the `selectedXPoint` variable. This is indeed set in my chart component, however the ngOnChange method is never called. The only way I seem to be able to see the updated value of my `selectedXPoint` in my `ChartComponent` is if I poll it somehow. I've used a `setInterval` to regularly check on the variable and see that it is in fact updated by the map component. I would however rather not rely on polling the variable every few seconds to see if it has changed. Does anyone perhaps have an idea?

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnChange, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Axis, Point, SelectedElement, Series, YAxis } from '@fire/chart';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart-component',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html'
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnChange {
  @Input() public selectedXPoint = -1;
  @Output() public pointSelected = new EventEmitter<Point>();


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}




  public ngOnInit() {

  }
  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
  }



  public onChartClickEvent(event: any) {
    const point: Point | undefined = this.getPoint(event);
    this.pointSelected.emit(point);
    this.selectedElement = event;
    console.log(event);
  }


  private getPoint(element: SelectedElement): Point | undefined {
    if (element.seriesElements.length === 0) {
      return Point.getDummyPoint();
    }
    const xAxisValue = typeof(element.xAxisValue) === 'string' ? parseInt(element.xAxisValue) : element.xAxisValue;

    return this._points.find((value: Point) => {
      return value.id_dist === xAxisValue;
    });
  }
}
```

And the template that goes with it:

```
<div style="height:500px" *ngIf="series">
  <chart
    [legendVisible]="true"
    [xAxis]="getXAxis()"
    [yAxis]="yAxis"
    (selectedElementEvent)="onChartClickEvent($event)"
    [lineMarkerColor]="bubbleColor"
    [selectedElement]="selectedElement"
    [enableLineMarker]="true"
    [seriesArray]="series"
  >
  </chart>
</div>
```

My Map Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Point } from '@fire/chart';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-geomap',
  templateUrl: './geomap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./geomap.component.css']
})
export class GeomapComponent {
  public lat = 50.190968;
  public lng = 14.194336;
  public center = [this.lat, this.lng];
  public zoom = 6;
  public minZoom = 1;
  public maxZoom = 18;
  public pointZoom = 18;
  public selectedXPoint = 1;

  public onPointSelected(point: Point) {
    if (point.longitude && point.latitude) {
      this.lat = point.latitude;
      this.lng = point.longitude;
      this.zoom = this.pointZoom;
      this.center = [this.lat, this.lng];
    }
  }

  public focusChart(event: any) {
    this.selectedXPoint = event.containerPoint.x;

  }

}
```

My map template:

```
<div style="height:40%">
  <map
    [perfectView]="true"
    [zoom]="zoom"
    [center]="center"
    (markerClicked)="focusChart($event)"
  >
  </map>
</div>
<div>
  <app-chart-component
    (pointSelected)="onPointSelected($event)"
    [selectedXPoint]="selectedXPoint"
  ></app-chart-component>
</div>
```

Comment: at least a typo on quick initial look: `ngOnChange` should be `ngOnChanges`

Comment: Yeah thanks for that. That wasn't copied from the code but rather entered in when I created the question.

Comment: can you try and force change detection after `this.selectedXPoint = event.containerPoint.x`, import `ChangeDetectorRef`, inject in constructor and call `detectChanges()`. These third party libs sometimes runs outside angular change detection.

Comment: @AJT82 This is brilliant and works a treat. Submit this as an answer and I'll happily accept that.

Comment: done! Glad to hear it solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party libraries sometimes run outside of angular change detection, in those cases you can force angular to run change detection by using `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges` as follows:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// ...

constructor(private cRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

public focusChart(event: any) {
  this.selectedXPoint = event.containerPoint.x;
  this.cRef.detectChanges();
}
```